# AES Password Encryption

Tags: encryption

Can anyone explain how this string has likely been encrypted at all?

```
 AES256:29://(Hex://5B18C3AD8CFR4D38)
```

I've never seen an encryption has like this before in my life. Would it be possible to replicate with PHP? (Providing I can get what salts etc may have been used etc).

This is for a migration of data from one website to another - currently this data is stored in a MSSQL DB but will be used in MySQL if PHP can handle the encryption.

Comment: check out php mcrypt if u havent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be part of a 256bit hash with some metadata around it.  I'm not familiar with the php libraries for encryption but know that you can create a 256bit sha with php and there should be a toHex() method.

To check a password, encrypt the users entry with sha256 and check its hex value against the one stored.  Have you checked to see if its the first 1/4 of a sha?  Maybe they just truncate for lack of security?

If I had the guess, the 29 is probably userid, but could be a salt or something.

Comment: Thanks, I broke it down a bit and sorted it out - never thought of the extra number being an ID or other identifier.